# std::find_if -- how do I do a C# FirstOrDefault on that?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

I have this code below. I need to change it so that I can handle the scenario where the fields may not be found. I need to write zeros in that scenario. What is the most compact way to do that? I can use C++ 14. It seems that I need something like a FirstOrDefault operator from C# for the iterator returned from `find_if`. I then need a function pointer to one that runs the Convert or one that returns 0f. It's not clear to me how to do that in C++. (I come from C# land; I'm not too great at this-or-that function approaches in C++.)

```
      auto xField = *std::find_if(msg->fields.begin(), msg->fields.end(), 
[](const sensor_msgs::msg::PointField& f){ return f.name == "x"; });
      auto yField = *std::find_if(msg->fields.begin(), msg->fields.end(), 
[](const sensor_msgs::msg::PointField& f){ return f.name == "y"; });
      auto zField = *std::find_if(msg->fields.begin(), msg->fields.end(), 
[](const sensor_msgs::msg::PointField& f){ return f.name == "z"; });

      // TODO: fill with 0f for any missing fields (and don't crash if they're missing)

      for(auto p = 0; p < msg->data.size(); p += msg->point_step) {
        auto x = ConvertToFloat(xField, &msg->data[p + xField.offset]);
        auto y = ConvertToFloat(yField, &msg->data[p + yField.offset]);
        auto z = ConvertToFloat(zField, &msg->data[p + zField.offset]);

        point_cloud.emplace_back(x, y, z);
      }
```

Comment: I don't think there is a "compact" way, you'll need to write a custom function for that. Also, currently your code will crash if one find cannot find anything

Comment: I would just write a wrapper function.  Pass in the string and the default value and have it spit out the found item or the default.  That makes the call site look cleaner too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual pattern for situations like this is to write a wrapper function that basically does:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), ...);

if (iter == collection.end() {
    return default_value;
}

return *iter;
```

You can template that thing to your heart’s content. But I’d keep it simple for now. You can always make it a template later if it turns out to be a standard pattern you need for several different types.